# XPath : Parsing a page

Tags: php, xpath

Let's say I have this HTML:

```
<div class="area">Area One</div>
<div class="key">AAA</div>
<div class="value">BBB</div>
<div class="key">CCC</div>
<div class="value">DDD</div>
<div class="key">EEE</div>
<div class="value">FFF</div>
<div class="area">Area Two</div>
```

I want to use XPath to make an array:

```
my_array['area']
     [0] => 
          ['AAA'] => "BBB"
          ['CCC'] => "DDD"
          ['EEE'] => "FFF"
     [1] => ...
```

And so on. Any thoughts on how this can be accomplished? What I'm trying to do is use "area" as the marker between sub-arrays.

Answer (score 0):

My knowledge is somewhat limited in PHP but you can try :

```
<?php
$html = <<<'HTML'
<div class="area">Area One</div>
<div class="key">AAA</div>
<div class="value">BBB</div>
<div class="key">CCC</div>
<div class="value">DDD</div>
<div class="key">EEE</div>
<div class="value">FFF</div>
<div class="area">Area Two</div>
<div class="key">GGG</div>
<div class="value">HHH</div>
<div class="key">III</div>
<div class="value">JJJ</div>
<div class="key">KKK</div>
<div class="value">LLL</div>
HTML;
$document = new DOMDocument();
$document->loadHTML($html);
$xpath = new DOMXpath($document);

$nbarea = count($xpath->query('//*[contains(text(),"Area")]'));

$i=1;
$j=1;

for ($a = 1; $a <= $nbarea; $a++) {

    for ($b = 1; $b <= 3; $b++) {
        $element1 = $xpath->query('//*[contains(text(),"Area")]['.$i.']/following::div['.$j.']');
        $j++;
        $element2 = $xpath->query('//*[contains(text(),"Area")]['.$i.']/following::div['.$j.']');

        $h1 = $element1->item(0)->nodeValue;
        $h2 = $element2->item(0)->nodeValue;

        $area[$i-1][$h1] = $h2;
        $j++;
    }

$i++;
$j=1;
}

print_r($area)

?>
```

Output :

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [AAA] => BBB
            [CCC] => DDD
            [EEE] => FFF
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [GGG] => HHH
            [III] => JJJ
            [KKK] => LLL
        )

)
```

Side note : I've assumed you always have the same number of elements for each area (=3).